Unconventional text file format: Mapping "dangling" text as column names
What would be a good method to get the labeled column names below to be placed as the actual column names for the numeric fields in the (abridged) text file below?



# Stream: MPDE1 Air











# URL: http://172.17.0.1:8081/joule









#









# start:             2014-05-18 20:57:40 +0000









# end:               2029-09-02 21:49:57 +0000









# total time:        over 15 years









# total rows:        1193









# decimation factor: 1024









# notes:









# legend:









#                    Column 1: time (us)









#                    Column 2: MPDE1 Charge Air Pressure (no units)









#                    Column 3: MPDE1 Charge Air Temperature (no units)









#                    Column 4: MPDE1 Start Air Pressure (no units)









#                    Column 5: MPDE1 Crankcase Pressure (no units)









#                    Column 6: MPDE1 Control Air MTU Pressure (no units)









#                    Column 7: MPDE1 Control Air local Pressure (no units)









#                    Column 8: MPDE1 Intake Air Temperature (no units)









#









# --------- MATLAB INSTRUCTIONS ------------









#









# this file can be loaded directly into MATLAB









#









#   >> x = importdata('~/Downloads/filename.csv')









#   x =









#       data: [1737x15 double] % the data









#   textdata: {41x1 cell}      % this help text









#









1.587141691471679e+15
87.0
356.0
1087.5
2.200000047683716
174.0
-0.20000000298023224
356.0


1.588982371460937e+15
87.0
356.0
1087.5
2.200000047683716
174.0
0.06386884301900864
356.0


1.589596771472655e+15
0.0
91.60917663574219
291.8644714355469
0.0
67.76226043701172
0.25987645983695984
84.54258728027344


1.589658211465819e+15
2.0390625
113.2216796875
379.10101318359375
0.05152728036046028
93.59890747070312
1.5738410949707031
91.5315170288086


1.589719651469726e+15
0.0
92.08888244628906
424.5111389160156
0.0
91.92170715332031
2.584010124206543
83.6112289428711


1.589781091454101e+15
0.0
89.78622436523438
424.4468078613281
0.0
91.99052429199219
3.7338995933532715
81.59453582763672


1.589842531461913e+15
0.0
89.03964233398438
424.583740234375
0.0
91.93624114990234
5.337348937988281
80.92362213134766


1.589903971429687e+15
0.05742187425494194
101.93095397949219
425.06207275390625
-0.00048828125
91.98717498779297
7.536652088165283
80.07470703125


1.589965411471679e+15
0.0
88.92433166503906
425.7071838378906
0.0
92.02363586425781
8.792312622070312
78.72703552246094


1.590026851453125e+15
0.0
76.87582397460938
425.2920227050781
0.0
91.92735290527344
10.360462188720703
73.7714614868164


1.590088291436523e+15
0.9345703125
72.80612182617188
432.24908447265625
-1.1497070789337158
92.85986328125
12.713504791259766
73.5042724609375


1.590149731455077e+15
0.4248046875
69.1480712890625
428.84393310546875
-1.4775390625
92.64044189453125
14.61204719543457
70.16329956054688


1.590211171464843e+15
0.0
68.83126831054688
424.8350830078125
0.0
91.89635467529297
17.992916107177734
68.66358947753906


1.590272611469726e+15
0.0
93.70545196533203
424.22998046875
0.0
91.79979705810547
20.77794647216797
78.2529067993164




your question is not clear. Please mock up the expected result in a data sample. Also, please show the code you have already tried and explain what aspect didn't work for you.

Quick and dirty.

let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Column1", type text}, {"Column2", type text}, {"Column3", type text}, {"Column4", type text}, {"Column5", type text}, {"Column6", type text}, {"Column7", type text}, {"Column8", type text}}),
    #"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(#"Changed Type", each Text.StartsWith([Column1], "# Column")),
    #"Removed Other Columns" = Table.SelectColumns(#"Filtered Rows",{"Column1"}),
    columnNames = Table.TransformColumns(#"Removed Other Columns", {{"Column1", each Text.AfterDelimiter(_, ": "), type text}}),
    #"Transposed Table" = Table.Transpose(columnNames),
    Custom1 = #"Changed Type",
    #"Filtered Rows1" = Table.SelectRows(Custom1, each [Column2] <> null),
    #"Appended Query" = Table.Combine({#"Transposed Table", #"Filtered Rows1"}),
    #"Promoted Headers" = Table.PromoteHeaders(#"Appended Query", [PromoteAllScalars=true])
in
    #"Promoted Headers"

